# Is reading a python csv file backwards slower?

Tags: python, csv

If I  am trying to find lines a few thousand lines in a 750Gb csv file using the python `csv` package and I believe all the lines are in the second half of the file, is it faster to read the file backwards? Is there any performance hit when reading a file backwards?

Comment: You cannot read a file backward. There is no such facility.

Comment: you could seek somewhere and get in sync with the next end of line separator (not valid for multi-line csv files).

Comment: Reading a CSV backwards would be difficult and slow. I’d seek to the middle and find the nearest quote mark (though that could be arbitrarily far… if you know there aren’t any, that step can be skipped). Or actually try not to have a 750 GB CSV in the first place (load it into an SQL database or something).

Comment: ... but that still would read forward. the actual issue is lookup complexity.

Comment: @DyZ reversed() ?

Comment: 750 GB csv file? you should really consider using a (proper) DB instead

Comment: @Asdf11 `reversed()` works on a `list`. so you have to read the full file first, there's no magic.

Comment: If this is a one time operation, probably best to just deal with it being slow.  I agree with the comments that if you have to do this repeatedly you should be reading this into a DB and then doing a DB Query... Python is not the right tool for doing this.  You could potentially set up a producer-consumer chain that spits out lines to multiple `grep` type processes.  Actually, now that I think of it... `cat huge.csv | grep <your expr>` is probably a better bet than Python